# Почему метод poll() интерфейса Queue<E> не возвращает элемент из очереди?

Tags: java, дерево

Решаю задачку https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/swap-nodes-algo
обмен под-деревьев у указанного дерева на определенном уровне.
Если указать уровень на котором требуется обменять под-деревья, равным 4. То при непустой очереди метод poll() не возвращает объект из очереди.
Вот код:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

public class Solution {

public static void swapNode(Node root, int K) {
    int depth = 1;
    Queue<Node> level = new LinkedList<>();
    if (depth == K) {
        Node temp = root.left;
        root.left = root.right;
        root.right = temp;
    } else {
        Queue<Node> qu = new LinkedList<>();
        qu.offer(root);

        while (depth < K) {

            while (!qu.isEmpty()) {
                Node curr = null;
                curr = qu.poll();
                level.add(curr.left);
                level.add(curr.right);

            }
            while (!level.isEmpty()) {
                qu.offer(level.remove());
            }
            K--;
        }
        while (!qu.isEmpty()) {
            Node temp = null;
            Node n = qu.poll();
            temp = n.left;
            n.left = n.right;
            n.right = temp;
        }

    }

}

public static void inorder_print(Node root) {
    if (root != null) {
        inorder_print(root.left);
        System.out.print(root.data + " ");
        inorder_print(root.right);
    }
}

public static void printNode(Node root, int K) {

    inorder_print(root);
    System.out.println();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node root = new Node(1);
    Queue<Node> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(root);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    Node curr;
    while (N-- > 0) {
        curr = list.poll();
        int leftData = sc.nextInt();
        int rightData = sc.nextInt();
        curr.left = (leftData == -1) ? null : new Node(leftData);
        curr.right = (rightData == -1) ? null : new Node(rightData);
        if (curr.left != null) list.add(curr.left);
        if (curr.right != null) list.add(curr.right);
    }
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    while (T-- > 0) {
        int K = sc.nextInt();
        swapNode(root, K);
        printNode(root, K);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо.
Надо было:

```
while (!qu.isEmpty()) {

    Node curr = null;
    curr = qu.poll();
    if (curr.left != null)level.add(curr.left);
    else level.add(new Node(-1));
    if (curr.right != null) level.add(curr.right);
    else level.add(new Node(-1));

}
```

В очереди был `null` объект. На нем возникало исключение `NullPointerException`.